# JS global variable remains unchanged

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I have 2 global variables and changing them into a function but it's still shows as undefined.

```
var lat
var long;
function getLocation()
{
    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else
    {
        console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}
function showPosition(position)
{
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    long = position.coords.longitude;
}
getLocation();
console.log(lat + "   " + long);
```

I have checked other questions on this site but none seem to have answer to this. When I check inside the showPostion() function, it shows actual coordinates. I am new to js please help.

**Edit:**

I have another function in which I want to access global variables.

```
function generate_list(params, fromPageLoad)
{
    var ajax_url = jQuery('#ajax_post_url').val();
    var data = { action: 'generate_list', latitude: lat, longitude: long };
    var extended_data = jQuery.extend(data, params);

    jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: extended_data,
    url: ajax_url,
    success: function (data) {
            //console.log(data);}
}
```

This function is getting called on the loading of the page with dynamic parameters.

I also tried to return lat lang in showPosition() but it's not working. The 'POST' or 'GET' method doesn't return coordinates variable.

```
function showPosition(position)
    {
        var ajax_url = jQuery('#ajax_post_url').val();
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var long = position.coords.longitude;
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: { lat: lat,long: long },
            url: ajax_url,
            success: function(data)
            {
            }
        });

        console.log("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
            "Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
    }
```

If user allow the location, I want to change the list.

Comment: You're changing them in `showPosition` but calling `getLocation` so nothing changes ;)

Comment: getLocation is calling showPosition

Comment: FYI, the last example in [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1541563) makes this an exact duplicate.

Comment: `showPosition` will be called back **if and when** the location is resolved. That will happen **sometime later**.

Comment: Why isn’t that last snippet working exactly?

Comment: it shows coordinates on console.log but doesn't show it in POST or GET. I tried both

Comment: @deceze likely because `generate_list()` is called before `showPosition()` is.

Comment: @the_badev have you looked at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60894066/1541563) yet?

Comment: Yes patrick, I am working on it.

Comment: @deceze I revoke my previous comment. This question does not contain a [mcve]. You're right. I've gone ahead and deleted my answer.

Comment: storing data in global variables is not the way to pass it between functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is async API. Try moving console.log inside `function showPosition(position)`.
A lot (if not all) of APIs with `callback` are async. Be careful out there!

Comment: Inside showPosition() is working, but I want to pass coordinates to another function so I assigned it to global variable.

Comment: just call the function inside showPosition()?

Comment: because actually the global variables are changed, so if that function is run at later time, it should be able to get the lat and long. If it runs immediately, it needs to be in showPosition()

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not add another function into showPosition() as it loads on loading of the page.

Comment: @the If you can assign to global variables from it, why can’t you call other code from within it? You will have to do that one way or another.

Comment: The other function has parameters and that parameters are set dynamically from another file.

Comment: @deceze it's common for the consumer to know about the resource (in this case, a function in another file knows about the global variables), and sometimes it doesn't make sense to refactor the source code of the resource to call all the consumers. In this case, an easier refactor would be to store the result as a global promise instead of mutable globals `lat` and `long`.

Comment: @the_badev if you can edit your question to highlight why it's inconvenient to call your other function from within `showPosition()`, I'll vote to re-open your question and explain my comment above with actual code.

Comment: I edited my question with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Answer you dear friend

```
let lat;
let long;
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, null, {});

function success(pos) {
  lat = pos.coords.latitude
  long = pos.coords.longitude

  console.log('lat =',lat)
  console.log('long =',long)

}
```

Comment: running this as a snippet doesn't work

Comment: I want to pass lat , long to another function and that's why I need the values in global variable. This didn't work.